# Why would anyone ever use apply with margin=2?

Tags: r

Why would ever anyone choose `apply(.,margin=2,.)` over `sapply(.,.)`.

```
sapply(mtcars,sum)
apply(mtcars,2,sum)
```

The second one with `apply` seems to be verbose.

1. Is there a deeper sense for apply with margin=2?
2. Is it a historical leftover and `sapply` was defined/invented after `apply`.

@Friendly helpers: (I see the point.)

```
m<-matrix(1:9,ncol=3)
sapply(m,sum)
apply(m,1,sum)
```

Comment: apply is meant for matrices (and arrays more generally)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use `apply` with matrices (or more generally arrays). It was never intended for data.frames but for convenience accepts data.frames (and other objects) as input (although internally it immediately applies `as.matrix`).

You are completely right that it shouldn't be used to iterate over data.frame columns. However, I generally would use `lapply` or `vapply` (and not `sapply`) for that.